# JBoss throws ClassNotFoundException com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.resolver.CatalogManager only when deploying on linux server

Tags: java, jboss-eap-7

I'm trying to move a working JBoss EAP 7.2 installation with a working deployment from Windows to Linux. To do so, I copied the EAP directory to linux. When starting the deployment fails with:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.company.app.core.services.foo.message.FooMessageClientProducer]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/org/apache/xml/internal/resolver/CatalogManager
        at deployment.my-deployment.war//org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:184)
        at deployment.my-deployment.war//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:117)
        at deployment.my-deployment.war//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:300)
        ... 51 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/org/apache/xml/internal/resolver/CatalogManager
        at deployment.my-deployment.war//com.sun.xml.ws.util.xml.XmlUtil.createDefaultCatalogResolver(XmlUtil.java:296)
        at deployment.my-deployment.war//com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.createCatalogResolver(WSServiceDelegate.java:348)
        at deployment.my-deployment.war//com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.parseWSDL(WSServiceDelegate.java:334)
        at deployment.my-deployment.war//com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.<init>(WSServiceDelegate.java:292)
        at deployment.my-deployment.war//com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.<init>(WSServiceDelegate.java:201)
        at deployment.my-deployment.war//com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.<init>(WSServiceDelegate.java:182)
        at deployment.my-deployment.war//com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.<init>(WSServiceDelegate.java:178)
        at deployment.my-deployment.war//com.sun.xml.ws.spi.ProviderImpl.createServiceDelegate(ProviderImpl.java:89)
        at deployment.my-deployment.war//javax.xml.ws.Service.<init>(Service.java:82)
        at deployment.my-deployment.war//com.company.app.foo.generated.message.Service.<init>(Service.java:56)
        at deployment.my-deployment.war//com.company.app.core.services.foo.message.FooMessageClientProducer.<init>(FooMessageClientProducer.java:28)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
        at deployment.my-deployment.war//org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:172)
        ... 53 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.resolver.CatalogManager from [Module "deployment.my-deployment.war" from Service Module Loader]
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:255)
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:410)
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:116)
        ... 69 more
```

Since this deployment works just fine on Windows, I'm puzzled.
Both systems use Oracle JDK 11.0.1+13. Windows 10 and Ubuntu 18.04. Deleted jboss tmp files. The server is able to start without a deployment.

---

### Workaround

When providing a dependency including the missing class, the deployment works on Linux, too. This is to be expected, however I still don't understand why this issue only occurs on Linux.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal</groupId>
  <artifactId>resolver</artifactId>
  <version>20050927</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Have a look at this thread and it looks to be you need to pack the dependency in the application ear/war https://developer.jboss.org/thread/261982

Comment: FYI the Jboss7.x tag isn't really appropriate as it concerns JBoss *AS* 7, which is the version on which the JBoss EAP 6.x were based. For JBoss EAP 7.2 I guess the appropriate versioned tag would be [tag:wildfly-14], although it'd be much better if we had JBoss EAP-specific tags

Comment: @Aaron Turns out there are eap specific tags available -- fixed.

Comment: Nice, glad to learn that !

Comment: @Naveen Thanks but as stated this deployment actually works when the server is started on Windows instead of Linux. Hence I'm wary about modifying the deployment itself.